# Displaying 2 graphs using JUNG

Tags: java, jung

Using [JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net), I am able to draw one graph at a time. However, I need to display 2 independent graphs (already populated) by overlapping one over the other (perhaps with different vertex/edge colors). How do I do that? I am not able to see any mechanism to add a new graph to already existing layout.

Does JUNG support this?

Regards,

Salil

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [SubLayoutDemo](http://jung.sourceforge.net/site/jung-samples/xref/edu/uci/ics/jung/samples/SubLayoutDemo.html), which uses [AggregateLayout](http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/algorithms/layout/AggregateLayout.html).

Comment: Thanks @Joshua, I will check it out. As of now, I was using the oldest and noblest technique of using a `LayeredPane` and then adding these layouts one by one. But perhaps this will save me some time and complexity. I will check if I find any problems and get back to you.